# What is the fastest way to obtain the eigenvalues of a Wishart matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, random

I would like a fast method of creating a sample of random numbers which corresponds to the eigenvalues of a Wishart matrix:

[image: definition of Wishart matrix]

For M>N the eigenvalues \lambda_i are given by the jpd

[image: eigenvalue distribution]

Where $K_N$ is a normalisation constant and $\beta = 1,2$ depends on whether $X$ is real or complex. Does anyone have any suggestions for a fast way of implementing this? My goal is to play with multiple realisations of eigenvalues representing 100x100 matrices.

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Ok, here is a very basic example:

```
n = 1000;
m = 1001;
μ = 0;
σ = 1/Sqrt[n];
AbsoluteTiming[
a = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], {n, m}];
wish = a.a\[ConjugateTranspose];
ewish = Eigenvalues@wish;
]
ewishPlot = Histogram[ewish, {0.1}, "PDF"];

ηp = n σ^2 (1 + Sqrt[η])^2;
ηm = n σ^2 (1 - Sqrt[η])^2;
η = m/n;
ρmp[λ_] := 1/(2 π n σ^2 λ)Sqrt[(ηp - λ) (λ - ηm)];
ρmpPlot = Plot[ρmp[λ], {λ, 0, 4}];
Show[ρmpPlot, ewishPlot]
```

I guess speed won't be a problem but I would still very much like to know the best way of doing this.

Comment: Do you have a slow method now? Wishart matrices are trivial to construct and `Eigenvalues` on 100x100 machine number matrices should be very fast as well...

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node553.html). I would've done that probably differently now, but that could be a start.

Comment: In fact, about 6 years ago I was generating a bunch of these for betas 2 and 4 (IIRC), to study eigenvalue statistics in the context of applications to QCD (Dirac operator in Random Matrix Theory), so I could probably dig up some of that code, but what is in the book can also be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks great!

Comment: What you have looks pretty good to me (this is how I've done it). The alternate that I know of is "cleaner", but very slow — ``Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"];
eigs = Eigenvalues@RandomReal[WishartDistribution[σ IdentityMatrix@n, m]]`` You might want to define your functions with `:=`... see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487/5) for the difference between `=` and `:=`

Comment: Why is that slower? I would have expected that if there is a built in function called "WishartDistribution" it would be better to use it than build one from scratch.

Comment: Because it is implemented more generally than what you've done here. You can use a non-diagonal Sigma and it uses MultinormalDistribution to generate the data. In any case, the core part of it is implemented the same way as yours, so I don't see a reason to look for a different way. It's probably as efficient as it can be.

Answer (score 3):

Since all the entries of $X$ are i.i.d. normal, it can be converted into a band diagonal matrix with $\chi$-distributed components via elementary reflections. A paper discusses about this is "Matrix Models for Beta Ensembles" and can be found in [this arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0206043).

The Wishart matrix constructed in this way is tridiagonal and can be represented as `SparseArray` in Mathematica. The eigenvalues can be obtained efficiently by using `Eigenvalues` with method `"Banded"`.

Answer (score 2):

One can now use `MatrixPropertyDistribution[]` along with `WishartMatrixDistribution[]` to generate the eigenvalues of a random Wishart matrix. For instance,

```
RandomVariate[MatrixPropertyDistribution[Eigenvalues[X], 
              X \[Distributed] WishartMatrixDistribution[4, IdentityMatrix[4]]], 5]
```

will generate $5$ sets of eigenvalues of random $4\times4$ Wishart matrices.